# IE8 issue two columns merging in single column

Tags: asp.net, html, aspxgridview

I have problem in IE 8 that merges two column data in one column. I am working on dynamic website with asp .net code. can you please give me solution for this issue?

In FF code is like this

```
<tr class="rowstyle">
        <td align="center" class="wt30">
            <img src="../images/attachment_icon.png" id="lnkAttachment">
        </td>
        <td align="center" class="wt30">
            <img class="" onclick="" src="../images/nohistory.png" title="" alt="History" id="lnkHistory">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

But in IE8 it looks like this

```
<tr class="rowstyle">
        <td align="center" class="wt30">
            <img src="../images/attachment_icon.png" id="lnkAttachment">
            <img class="" onclick="" src="../images/nohistory.png" title="" alt="History" id="lnkHistory">
        </td>

    </tr>
```

Comment: Not sure how this would be possible. Are you saying that IE renders the `TD` differently thatn FF?

Comment: yes in all other browser it looks fine.. only IE8 merges data of two columns..

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine with my IE., try giving border attribute and they look the same

```
<table border=1px></table>
```